# Error:No such property: VERSION_NAME MaterialTabs Library for class: org.gradle.api.publication.maven.internal.deployer.DefaultGroovyMavenDeployer

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, pagerslidingtabstrip

After checking out the project https://github.com/pizza/MaterialTabs, I started building the project and got the following error.

Error:No such property: VERSION_NAME for class: org.gradle.api.publication.maven.internal.deployer.DefaultGroovyMavenDeployer

Thanks in Adavance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `build.gradle` in the root folder uses these variables.

```
   version = VERSION_NAME
    group = GROUP
```

Just define a `gradle.properties` file in the root of the project and add:

```
VERSION_NAME=XXX  //example 1.0.0
GROUP=com.mylibrary
```